# Solr PatternTokenizer regex for double quotes

Tags: java, regex, solr

I would like to use " as a token seperatior for the input by using PatternTokenizer. My setting in schema.xml is of the following

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s\.,!(){\[\]:}\"]+"/>
```

But this one failed since the second " is mistook for the closing of pattern (Solr cannot start with it). How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Try `pattern="[\s.,!(){\[\]:}\u0022]+"` or `pattern="[\s.,!(){\[\]:}&quot;]+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Why you do not post an answer so I can upvote for you:) Worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the line to

```
pattern="[\s.,!(){\[\]:}&quot;]+"
```

The literal quote must be replaced with the XML entity.

As an alternative, you may use `\u0022` that will be correctly parsed by the regex engine as a literal double quote.